# Rendering 2D vertical fluid movement/physic with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl, fluid-dynamics

I'm trying to find data and examples for 2D fluid movements and physics that could be rendered using webGL or 2d-canvas.

My objective is to reproduce the animation that we can see for example on this front page : https://fresh.deno.dev/

I'm absolutely not familiar with the 2D-3D rendering and animation, so I would be more than happy to have recommandations about this subject.

Answer (score 0):

You use Google's "[LiquidFun](https://google.github.io/liquidfun/)", as you are not familiar with 2D rendering.